# Curl does not connect through Hostname

Tags: linux

I am trying to configure SumoCollectors in linux servers, but curl connectivity is not working if I try without any wait time .

If I run `curl --max-time 900 -v collectors.au.sumologic.com:443` with wait time , then it connects to Sumo Collector after waiting for few minutes.

Another thing is curl connects to IP's of collectors.au.sumologic.com without any issue .

What could be the issue ? I have already ruled out firewall and DNS issue.

Comment: Check your dns configuration and dns caching.

Comment: 1. How exactly did you rule out DNS and firewall issues? 2. If you run `curl` with `-v` flag, you should be able to see at which point it got stuck which might give you some clue. You can [edit] your question and add the output of your verbose `curl` command, and show where it got stuck. 3. You can also try running curl under the following `strace` command: `strace -e trace=network -tt -T -yy curl...` which might provide additional hint on where it got stuck.